# Special characters in IsolatedStorage name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, special-characters, isolatedstorage

I have the problem that if special characters (apart from full stops, colons, and dashes) are used in an `IsolatedStorage` file name my application crashes.

Is there any work-around for using these special character in the `IsolatedStorage` file name.

If not how can I remove all the special characters?

Side note: I'm taking the input for the file name from a TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this [Input Scope](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/07/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-26-what.html). Just set the input scope to "Filename".
There are ways to work around via code or xref table but more elegant (IMO) to just limit what can be entered.

Comment: If you expect your users to enter an file name then you should use a preventive approach like @TheBrain suggests.  Don't strip out the chars in code, and then change the filename, instead prevent them from entering them in the first place. InputScope exists for this purpose

Comment: The `Filename` and `FullFilePath` input scope allows users to enter invalid characters such "\", "/", "?", "<" etc... (unless these are allowed in Isolated Storage? I haven't tried but they're not valid on Windows)

Comment: How would I go about implementing this input scope then?

Answer (score 1):

There are certain characters that filenames can't contain such as `<`, `>`, `|` etc... You could use this method to remove any special characters found in the textbox

```
string cleanedFilename = RemoveSpecialCharacters(myTextBox.Text);

public string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        if(Char.IsLetter(c))
           sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can also detect if there are any non-letter characters to validate the TextBox. You can then let the user know that there are unsupported characters. Simply modify the method above

```
public bool ContainsNonLetters(string input)
{
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        if(!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
           return true;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

When the user submits, you can perform a check.

```
if(ContainsNonLetters(filename))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please use alphanumeric characters only");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Filename seems fine");
}
```

If you want to allow non-alphanumeric characters, then you can have a list of characters not allowed and check if any character in the filename exists in that list.